# Computing $a^x$ with $x$ irrational via sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a\in\mathbb R$, $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$, be a fixed real number and define $f: \mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ setting:

$$f(x):=\lim_{n\to \infty} a^{r_n}$$
where $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$.

Is there any easy example where it is possible to compute explicitly $f(x)$ when $x$ is irrational?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you want $a > 0$ and   and $a \ne 1$.

Comment: Right, I've fixed it! Thanks for pointing it out ^.^

Answer (score 2):

$a^x=e^{xln(a)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(xln(a))^k}{k!}$, which can be computed directly.

Corredted.

Comment: +1, but I wonder whether this is the kind of explicit computation the OP has in mind.

Comment: I'm not a mind reader!

Comment: Understood. I was wondering, not criticizing.

Comment: Your original comment is valid, but I have no way of knowing what he wanted other than a solution.